# preg replace with regex list of characters returning empty string

Tags: php, regex

This should be basic but I am not getting it.

I would expect `echo preg_replace("/[\s.()-_]/", '', '(654)-098 98 .435.45');` to give me a string with only digits with no spaces. Instead I get a empty string.

What am I missing?

I made the regex (http://regex101.com/r/qO3nL9/1) and it looks correct.

Live: http://ideone.com/rlGKBa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `-` symbol at the last of character class, so that it would match the literal `-` symbol. In your pattern `)-_` inside the character class matches all the characters in the range  `)` to `_`(ie, `-` denotes the range not a literal `-` symbol). Numbers also falls within this range so it also got removed. See the characters which are falls within the range `)` to `_` in [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) page.

```
[\s.()_-]
```

Your code should be,

```
echo preg_replace("/[\s.()_-]/", '', '(654)-098 98 .435.45');
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qH7wQ9/3)

Comment: What is the difference? ie, why?

Comment: Ok, thank you! I see, makes sense, didn't think of that. Add also that its possible to escape it like `\-`. (and you could vote up [Utkanos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25095002/2427193) `/\D/` which is not what I asked but is the best solution here)

Comment: yep, i agree but he doesn't point out what's the actual problem with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', '(654)-098 98 .435.45');
```

Comment: That was smart, effective.